# How can I use refresh logo in my activity

Tags: android

Can anyone suggest me how can I use a refresh icon in my activity? I mean to say that my activity takes time to retrieve data from the server during that time I want to show the refreshed logo moving indicating the user that data retrieval is still in progress. So can anyone suggest to me how that can be done? If possible with an example.

Comment: why dont you use progress dialog to indicate

Comment: They need refresh icon, i told them about progress bar but their requirements needs refresh icon.do u know how that can be done

Comment: ok..i have use progress bar but i cant control its rotation...i want it to rotate for an particular seconds..how that can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).

For more information, here is a great article given: https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/asynctasks-with-progressdialogs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but what about creating your animation with the "refresh logo" you need?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list android:oneshot="false"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:duration="200" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_1_anim0" />
<item android:duration="200" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_1_anim1" />
<item android:duration="200" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_1_anim2" />
<item android:duration="200" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_1_anim3" />
<item android:duration="200" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_1_anim4" />
<item android:duration="200" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_1_anim5" />
</animation-list>
```

Playing with duration, you can display whatever you want at the time you want. [More info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html).

After, define and show your own CustomDialog, like [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog), instead of the standard progess dialog.

If your "refresh logo" is a static image, previus link should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog). There's also the [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) widget.

Comment: can you please tell me from where i started..if possible withexample

Answer (score 0):

create custom view , which contains a rotating portion of circle visible .